# Why does constructor choose type INT instead of SHORT when invoked with a parameter of type CHAR?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, constructor, overload-resolution

It's seen that in the below code the constructor with parameter of type `int` is being called. I know `int` is fine here. But why not `short`? as ASCII value of `'A'` gives 65 which a `short` can accommodate.

**On what criteria the constructor with the parameter of data type `int` is invoked?**

---

```
#include<iostream>

class RightData
{
    int x; 
    public:
    RightData(short data)
    {
        cout<< "Short" << endl;
    }
    RightData(int data)
    {
        cout<< "Int" << endl;
    }
    RightData(float data)
    {
        cout<< "Float" << endl;
    }
    ~RightData() 
    {
        cout<< "Final";
    }
};
int main()
{
    RightData *ptr = new RightData('A');
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result of [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) is `int` (not `short`) for `char`; and promotions (e.g. `char` -> `int`) have higher [ranking](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences) than other conversions (e.g. `char` -> `short`) in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

> prvalues of small integral types (such as `char`) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as `int`).
>
> - `signed char` or `signed short` can be converted to `int`;
> - `unsigned char`, `char8_t` (since C++20) or `unsigned short` can be converted to `int` if it can hold its entire value range, and `unsigned int` otherwise;
> - `char` can be converted to `int` or `unsigned int` depending on the underlying type: `signed char` or `unsigned char` (see above);

and (emphasis mine)

> Note that all other conversions are not promotions; for example, **[overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) chooses `char` -> `int` (promotion) over `char` -> `short` (conversion)**.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler always chooses the [best matching](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roger/cpp/week20.htm) overloading resolution.

in your case:

Type promotion is:

1. **A char, unsigned char or short can be promoted to an int. For example void f(int); can be a match for f('a');**
2. A float can be promoted to a double.
3. A bool can be promoted to an int (FALSE counts as 0, TRUE as 1).

Answer (score 4):

When casting implicitly, the compiler follows this [ranking](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution):

1. Exact match
2. Promotion
3. Conversion

Since, `char` to `int` is integral *promotion*, it takes precedence over `char` to `short` which is *conversion*.

From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) (emphasis mine):

> char can be **converted** to int or unsigned int depending on the underlying type: signed char or unsigned char